# How to verify array within object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, class, object

So I'm part of a bootcamp that helps you get job ready to do web development. I hit a snag and wanted to know if anyone could shed some light. `inTruth('I', 'is', 'dumb');` The goal is to have the Bootstrap class's method "registerStudent", verify if there is a matching object within it's array "students" if there is, it say "there is already a student registered", if not it will add the called method and add the object to the class's array. If my explanation isn't through. `runApology('I', 'am', 'sorry', * 2);`

HTML

```
<head>
    <title>Nucamp Community Coding Bootcamp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Nucamp Community Coding Bootcamp</h1>
    <script src="ReactWeek1Assignment.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

class Student {
    constructor(name, email, community) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.community = community;
    }
}
class Bootcamp {
    constructor(name, level, students = []) {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
        this.students = students;
    }
        registerStudent(studentToRegister) {
                if (this.students.filter(s => s === studentToRegister)){
                    this.students.push(studentToRegister);
                    console.log(`Registering ${studentToRegister.name} to ${this.name} with email ${studentToRegister.email}`);
                    return this.students;
                } else {
                    console.error(`${studentToRegister.name} is not registered`);
                    return this.students;
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/). It has many in-built comparison functions. You should use the isEqual() for the same. Kindly refer the following code.

```
_.isEqual(obj1,obj2);
```

For further reference you can refer this [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual).